# Spring JPA query from the results

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a tasks table. This table has a certain filter applicable. I will filter data from the table only if the filter value is not null (i,e) the filter value is provided from the front-end. I cannot write a SQL for each filter applicable. So I was wondering if there is any way to save the results and then query from the result if the filter is available.

```java
List<Task> filteredTasks = repository.findAll();

if (filter_1){
filteredTasks = filteredTasks.filterby(filter1)
}

if (filter_2){
filteredTasks = filteredTasks.filterby(filter2)
}
```

Can I do something like this?

Comment: Imho you can use specifications

Comment: @user9684181 where you able to solve it with the Predicate and CriteriaBuilder? The approach you mention is usually not suitable as you usually do not want to load a whole tables data into memory in your application and then filter.

Comment: If anyways you want to do it just search for "java stream filter"  to filter elements from a list

Answer (score 0):

You should filter directly when you query the database.

One approach to do this with JPA is using "Predicate" and "CriteriaBuilder" (you can find a good example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-and-or-criteria-predicates))

Another library very simple to use where you can make dynamic queries is [Jooq](https://www.jooq.org/)